# syntax error while compiling: SELECT statement from Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Iam trying to return data ( the stored exercises information : Name , period , burned calories that played by the user in a specific date)  from  Sqlite  database in my android app  , but an exception occur which is :

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling:    SELECT Name, Period, Burned_Calories FROM Exercise WHERE Date = Tuesday, 8/May/2012
```

why this exception occur, and  how i can solve it? please help me ..

this is my code :

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();
String selected_date= date_btn.getText().toString();

 Cursor c = db.getExerciseInfo(selected_date );

 if (c.moveToFirst())
 {
  do 
  {
    Toast.makeText(this ,"Name: "+ c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Period:" +c.getFloat(1)+ "\n" + " burned cals:" +c.getFloat(2)+ "\n" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
    while (c.moveToNext());

   }
  db.close();
```

> this is my method in the DBAdapter calss

```
public Cursor getExerciseInfo(String  date) throws SQLException
        {
       Cursor  C_excer = db.query(EXERCISE_TABLE_NAME, new String[]       {KEY_NAME,KEY_PERIOD,KEY_BURNEDCALS},KEY_DATE +" = " + date, null, null, null, null);
           if (C_excer != null) {
      C_excer.moveToFirst();
             }
        return C_excer;
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your date around quotes: '  '. like this:

```
 Cursor  C_excer = db.query(EXERCISE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_NAME,KEY_PERIOD, KEY_BURNEDCALS}, KEY_DATE + " = '" + date + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: thanks, but when i tried it , an error occur which is  invalid  character constant why is that ?

Comment: invalid character constant appears as error message , not in the log since i cant run  my app because of this error " when i try to run my app it says your app contain errors fix them "  , i dont know how to explain this type of error , do yo understand me ?

Comment: Sorry see my edit (I have changed a little thing in my code). Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of tough to tell from what you've posted, but your where clause looks suspicious:

```
WHERE Date = Tuesday, 8/May/2012 -- boom!
```

Try changing to this:

```
WHERE Date = 'Tuesday, 8/May/2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but maybe you need some quotes:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling:    SELECT Name, Period, Burned_Calories FROM Exercise WHERE Date = "Tuesday, 8/May/2012"
```